# how to refresh www directory in xcode/cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I've made changes to the www/index.html now I want it to be reflected in my app when I run it. But the simulator remains the same (the old index.html).

What is the command in cordova to "refresh" the app to include my changes?
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

this is what worked

```
cordova prepare ios
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: @TarynEast, I don't think it needs explanation, it's the command for that, just read the doc. http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: @foreyez, did you try my suggestion? Please leave a comment with some feedback

Comment: cordova prepare ios is the command to propagate the changes from the www folder to tue platforms/ios folder, it allows installing plugins in tne platform and updating www code. Just be aware that any changes made to the www folder in xcode will be lost and overwritten by the content of the root www folder of the project (there are many questions of people loosing their project after that command)

Comment: @QuickFix has given a great example of what I meant, foreyez

Answer (score -1):

Just rebuild the project and then run it from xcode when its complete

```
cordova build ios
```

Comment: this command seems wrong. correct command would be `cordova build ios` and it would not just update the platforms/ios folder, it would also build the project (calls prepare and then build).

Comment: Ah, you're right. I type it enough times a day you'd think I'd remember it

Comment: @kindasimple what you're saying would work, but that's if you want to recompile all binaries too, which is a lengthy process. I just asked about moving the static html files. cordova build call "prepare" internally which is what I asked.